# Angular nested directive is not compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two nested directives in my AngularJS project. The HTML is the following:

```
<body ng-app="main">
    <mainapp></mainapp>
</body>
```

An the `main.js` is the following:

```
var mainDirective = angular.module('main',
    [
        'app.config',
        'app.ui.menu'
    ]);

mainDirective.directive('mainapp', [
    'ConfigService',
    function(config)
    {
        return {
            restrict    : 'E',
            templateUrl : config.path.views + '/index.html'
        }
    }
]);
```

The content of the template is the following:

```
<menu-index></menu-index>
<div class="ui basic segment">
    <div class="ui vertically padded grid">
    More html here
```

For some reasons the `app.ui.module` is not working properly (I know that is included because I don't receive any error). This is the 'app.ui.module':

```
var menuIndex = angular.module('app.ui.menu', ['app.config']);

menuIndex.directive('menu-index', ['ConfigService', function(config)
{
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        templateUrl : config.path.views + '/menu/index.html'
    }
}]);
```

I don't know why the first `<main></main>` directive is working but the second `<menu-index></menu-index>` (the nested one) is not.

Comment: `main` is a standard HTML5 tag. I _think_ that shouldn't interfere with your using it as a directive, but for clarity it might be better to rename it.

Comment: Also, templates should be standalone HTML fragments; you can't just open `div` tags and close them in a subsequent template. I think the browser is going to insert `</div>` tags here automatically.

Comment: @Thomas I updated the code with your suggestion but it's still not working. I also noticed that if I rename `<mainapp></mainapp>` to `<main-app></main-app>` the whole main module is not working anymore.
Furthermore there are no HTML fragments, I just didn't write the code for the whole page to make the question easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a directive, by convention it is supposed to be camel cased:

```
menuIndex.directive('menuIndex', ...)
```

You have registered yours as `snake-case`

Comment: Thank you, you made my day! Are there other conventions for services, controllers and filters?

Comment: @siannone - Yes, but less often an impact on what you do. For instance, Angular really only has one type... a Provider. Everything else is just syntactic sugar around those. What this means is that even if you register a service as `.service('myService', ...)` you can still access it's provider using `'myServiceProvider'`.

Comment: Thank you again, I wish you a nice day.